# Can I keep track of what elements got clicked with alpine or htmx?

Tags: alpine.js, htmx

Look at this website, and on the left under "What dates might work?" you see a bunch of boxes selected, is it possible to keep track of what are selected and send them in a http post request or is it better to use javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to save the selected dates on the backend, I would suggest to use HTMX with the [`delay` trigger modifier](https://htmx.org/docs/#trigger-modifiers). A very simple example:

```
<form hx-post="date-save-endpoint" hx-trigger="change delay:2s">
    <input type="checkbox" name="dates" value="2022-04-01"> 2022-04-01
    <input type="checkbox" name="dates" value="2022-04-02"> 2022-04-02
    <input type="checkbox" name="dates" value="2022-04-03"> 2022-04-03
</form>
```

Here we have 2s delay, so HTMX will wait 2s for additional user inputs before sending a post request. Of course you can fine tune the delay to prevent some unnecessary requests.

Comment: Can I use it outside a form element? Like a row of buttons?

Comment: Yes, you can use HTMX everywhere. You may have to use different method to include the input values.

Comment: What do you mean different method? If the rows of buttons have name and value attributes won't htmx take those name and values?

Comment: By default if you attach HTMX on a form (like in my example), then HTMX will include all inputs' value in the post request. If you trigger a request on a non-form element, then you may have to include additional input elements in the request with [hx-include](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-include/) attribute. Otherwise only the value of the current (e.g. clicked) element will present in the request.